# Explicit conditions of breaking a loop at the top of the loop

Tags: javascript

I have the following loop, which loops through `required_types` array and finds linked objects:

```
for (var i = 0; i < required_types.length; i++)
{
    var linked_objects =linker.linked(required_types[i].type);
}
```

Now, I want to break the loop once I've found the type which has more than 0 objects linked, so in an accustomed way I'd do it like that:

```
var has_linked_objects = false;
for (var i = 0; i < required_types.length; i++)
{
    var linked_objects = ctx.linker.linked(required_types[i].type);
    var has_linked_objects = linked_objects > 0;
    if (has_linked_objects)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

However, I've recently read interesting chapter from *Code Complete* which states that exists from a loop should be as clear as possible and be stated in the beginning of the loop. This allows a reader to know all possible exit conditions before even examining the loop. So now I would write the loop in this way:

```
var has_linked_objects = false;
for (var i = 0; i < required_types.length && has_linked_objects === false; i++)
{
    var linked_objects = ctx.linker.linked(required_types[i].type);
    var has_linked_objects = linked_objects > 0;
}
```

Is the second option really a better choice that the first one? If so, why?

Comment: The second option doesn't seem correct because `has_linked_objects` is always false hence the condition `has_linked_objects === false` is always true.
In terms of code readability the second option is certainly better than the first one but a `while` loop would be even better.

Comment: @ToniToniChopper How is it better from a readability standpoint? You still need to go into the body of the loop to find out what changes the value of that control variable (`has_linked_objects` in this case), and anybody capable of doing that should also know how a simple `break` statement works.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I should have added "In my opinion" at the beginning of the second sentence because I guess it's subjective.

Comment: @ToniToniChopper Perhaps, but I already knew we were dealing with opinions. I'm genuinely curious as to why you think it's more readable, since I disagree for the reasons in my previous.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist The reason is very simple, I'm used to write the code in that way and avoid the break when possible. It's not a personal crusade or anything, just a matter of habits.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, this is bad advice. The condition could get very long and it no longer matches my mental "for-each" pattern.

I read this

```
for (var i = 0; i < required_types.length; i++) {
    if (has_linked_objects) {
        break;
    }
}
```

as

```
for each element in required_types { // easy
    if(found) {
        break;
    }
}
```

And I read this

```
for (var i = 0; i < required_types.length && has_linked_objects === false; i++) {
}
```

as

> Wow, this is a complicated loop! Let me read this carefully...
>   When does has_linked_objects change?
>   Could it change to true and change back to false in a single iteration of the loop?

I think it's much easier to think about simple conditions: “if this happens, then break” than to keep track of many variables in the loop body and test everything at once in the next iteration. The second approach could make it harder to write the rest of the function, because you can't be sure which condition triggered the end of the loop (was the element found or not?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method like this

```
if (required_types.some(function(cType){return ctx.linker.linked(cType) > 0;})) {
   ...
}
```

This breaks out of iterating the Array at the first iteration which returns `true`. If I have to choose between the two options you provided, I would choose the second (with the following fixed code)

```
var has_linked_objects = false;
for (var i = 0; i < required_types.length && has_linked_objects === false; i++)
{
    has_linked_objects = ctx.linker.linked(required_types[i].type) > 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't come remotely close to answering the question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist This answer offers a better choice, right?

Comment: He's explicitly asking if option B is better than option A, not if there are any better options. There's also the supplementary question asking *why* B is better or worse than A. Introducing option C, while potentially helpful, doesn't actually answer what's been asked.

Answer (score 1):

It is right, that you should put all conditions in the head of the loop **if possible**. If it is not possible or if it would make the code even less readable, you can - of course - use a break. In your case the loop is so small and simple that it probably won't make a huge difference. If you really want to make sure that fellow developers know what's going on, you can still write a comment that lists alternative exit points in the loop.

```
// Iterates required_types and breaks on an entry with linked objects
for (var i = 0; i < required_types.length; i++)
{
    ...
    if (has_linked_objects)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you need to further use the last used element in the array, having the second condition in the head of the loop introduces another issue. When the loop ends, `i` will always be 1 higher than your *result*. You will have to decrease `i` by one after the loop. Not that it's complicated to do that, but I, as someone who reads the code, would be confused for a second or two.

```
for (var i = 0; i < required_types.length && has_linked_objects === false; i++)
{
    ...
}
i--; // This can easily get overread or misinterpreted

var obj_with_linked_objects = required_types[i];
```

**TL/DR:** I personally prefer `break` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on this one - _When the loop ends, i will always be 1 higher than your result. You will have to decrease i by one after the loop._? I don't understand what result you're talking about

Comment: @Maximus I assumed that you search for an object in `required_types` that meets a condition and then further use it. To do this, you would need the last `i` used in the loop to know where this object is inside `required_types`. I'll update my answer to clarify it a little. Correct me, if I'm wrong.